# Images don't resolve correctly using Rails asset pipeline in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

**TL;DR** `asset_data_uri` works but `asset_path` does not.

I recently switched from a homegrown + jammit asset pipeline over to the Rails asset pipeline in hopes that I could ditch a bunch of code and have most everything taken care of for me. I have everything working fine in production (unlike most people on stackoverflow), however, in development mode images won't show up.

**I've noticed a few things.**

- In order to get images to show up correctly, I must precompile *in development mode* so they can be correctly referenced via css. Unfortunately, precompiling in dev mode precompiles javascript as well.
- When *not* precompiling in dev mode, images located in app/assets/images requested using `asset_data_uri()` show up fine. However, the same images using `asset_path()` do not. For example, in my initialize.css.erb file, `<%= asset_data_uri "cork.bg.gif" %>` displays fine, but `<%= asset_path "cork.bg.gif" %>` doesn't. This is because Rails resolves the path down to /assets/cork.bg.gif, and there's no image that lives in that location (i.e., public/assets/cork.bg.gif)
- Precompiling using `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development` gets me my images in the right spot so they can be served from public/assets, but it also stifles development because now changes to JS files are cached until I precompile again.

So what can I do? Here is the related configuration. Let me know if there's anything else I can provide:

**In application.rb:**

```
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

**In development.rb:**

```
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.debug = true
```

Note: I've read a bunch about `config.serve_static_assets` being involved. It's currently commented out in development.rb, so it's whatever the default version is on Rails 3.2.13.

**An example: initialize.css.erb**

My images are located in app/assets/images. The example image I'm using is located at app/assets/images/cork.bg.gif.

Works:

```
body {
  background-image: url(<%= asset_data_uri "cork.bg.gif" %>);
}
```

Doesn't work:

```
body {
  background-image: url(<%= asset_path "cork.bg.gif" %>);
}
```

Comment: Where are your images ?

Comment: Your comment isn't exactly correct: "This is because Rails resolves the path down to /assets/cork.bg.gif, and there's no image that lives in that location (i.e., public/assets/cork.bg.gif)". When the pipeline is enabled in development, it mounts a route at "/assets" that is served by Rails. That means it doesn't look in the public directory.

Comment: Can you verify `app/assets/images` is in your asset search path? Type `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` in the Rails console to see where Rails is searching.